# Replace secondary drive with bigger one, while keeping the data and letter (D:)

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have 2 HDD disks on my computer. The second one was some programs, git repositories and steam games. How can I clone the data to a bigger disk and replace it without having to configure all the programs? Essential how can I keep the letter D?

Comment: add disk to computer, download a program like gparted or easeus, use the copy partition functionality

Comment: Just clone the disk. Or if you do it manually, note that you can just change the driveletter at the end back to D after the old harddisk is removed, or you reassigned that driveletter. Once the new drive has the correct driveletter, reboot windows to ensure that all works correctly.

Comment: It was easier than I thought. Windows 10 allowed me to change the letter of the disk. Sorry for the noob question, but I mostly work with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments (thanks to [SimonS](https://superuser.com/users/458113/simons) and [LPChip](https://superuser.com/users/311586/lpchip)) I copy the content and change the letter using the Windows Disk Utility.
Most of the applications work after changing the letter.